# Is it possible to include multiple resources in one component in react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

Sometimes we want to see multilple business objects at once in an admin panel. For instance, I might want to display an customer profile along side with his/her list of accounting records. Or may be I want to keep an eye on both list of new cutomers and list of recent comments.

Is it possible to achieve with react-admin?

Comment: What are you calling an `admin panel` exactly ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Have a look at the Demo's [dashboard](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/demo/src/dashboard/Dashboard.tsx).

Get data from various sources with  `await dataProvider.getList(RESOURCE, PARAMS)` and pass that data to various components that can be displayed on one page.